# jQuery plugin to move a table row from one table to another table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Does anyone know a jQuery plugin in which I can move a table row from one table to another table? I know sortable with ConnectedLists, but I don't want no dragging, just moving the object with a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with jQuery.
Just use

```
tr.appendTo('#otherTable')
```

or

```
tr.prepend('otherTR')
```